# No focus on editable SelectOneMenue

Tags: user-interface, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu in my form. This component is editable. If I get focus on the selectOneMenu by `<tab>` the component is not editable. I have to click in the box for changing value. The dropdown list is not open by enter event too. I have to click on the dropdown button...
Here are some code snippets:

```
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{hoursView.selectedHourlyRate}"
                    id="hourlyRate" editable="true" scrollHeight="250"
                    validatorMessage="#{msg.valHourlyRate}"
                    converterMessage="#{msg.conHourlyRate}"
                    converter="doubleConverter" style="width:50%">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{hoursView.hourlyRateList}" id="test"
                        var="hourlyRate" itemLabel="#{hourlyRate.valueOut()}"
                        itemValue="#{hourlyRate.value}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

How can I edit the value of the component by getting focus on `<tab>`??

Comment: 11 years later I have the same issue ;-) Have you found a solution for your problem?